# Duplicate AndroidManifest.xml when built with Ant on CLI

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I have a project which uses an external library. Basically, it is a Android Library project with a libs folder containing the lib which is then built with ant.

I added the library project to the project.properties as usual. However, when I am using Eclipse to build the the project with the lib, I have no issues. When I try to build the same app on command line with ant, I get the following error:

```
[apkbuilder] Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml
[apkbuilder] Origin 1: C:\Develop\Projekte\Connected Car\AppBaukasten\cam_app-crash-detection\tests\bin\tests.ap_
[apkbuilder] Origin 2: C:\Develop\Projekte\Connected Car\AppBaukasten\3rd_android-support-v4\bin\classes.jar
```

What does eclipse do differently compared to ant?

Comment: by the way, the manifestMerger is already enabled in the main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by adding an empty source directory to the library project and by removing the source.dir property from the build.xml.